# How could I implement a halo to glow around my spaceship

Tags: unity, special-effects, glow

I have a 2D Spaceship sprite and I'm interested to know how I can create like a glow effect that leaves a trail behind the game object when it moves. Later on I am going to implement a dash function on the ship, so this glow trail should be consistent and visible.

Comment: A combination of an additive halo sprite and a TrailRenderer should accomplish this. Have you found these built-in Unity options aren't giving your desired result? If so, please show us what you have so far, and we should be able to help you solve the problems and achieve your target look.

Comment: As far as I have tried, it is pretty satisfying. Besides, I tried to download a particle asset that has interesting visuals. I would still be interested though how could I achieve such a glow/halo effect that leaves trail in a specific software.